# MATLAB: Access variables of a script in a function

Tags: matlab, function

This is a very basic question, but somehow, I am struck up with this.

Suppose there is a script

> Script1.m

```
a = 1;
b = 2;

function1()
```

And a function, function1 in function1.m

> function1.m

```
a = a/b;
end
```

Now when I run this, I get an error: 'Undefined function or variable "a".

I am familiar with C/C++, and I know that I can pass a, b as arguments to the function. But suppose 'a' contains a lot of data , which if passed through the function would consume a lot of time. So it won't be feasible to pass the variable.

Is there any other approach to achieve the same?

**Edit 1:**
Suppose I am using Pattern Search, or some other function which takes a function1 handle as an argument, then how do I pass variables local to script1 to function1.

Comment: You can pass `a` as a structure, sometimes it easier. If you donwt want pass it at all, you can declare it as `global`, it should be declared in all the functions that you use it.

Comment: @Adiel: Thank you. I was declaring global, but not in all the function. That was my mistake.

Comment: what's wrong with calling `function1` with input arguments: `function1( a, b )`? Matlas is not passing the arguments by value